# PHP or shell: How to randomize a list without back to back repeats?

Tags: php, bash, random

I wrote this in Linux BASH shell, but if there's a better solution in PHP that would be fine.

I need to produce a random selection from an array of 12 elements. This is what I've been doing so far:

```
# Display/return my_array that's been randomly selected:
# Random 0 to 11:
r=$(( $RANDOM % 12 ))
echo ${my_array[$r]}
```

Each time the call is made, it randomly selects an element. However, too often, it "randomly" selects the same element in a row sometimes several times. How can this be accomplish in BASH shell or PHP so make a random selection which is also not a repeat of the last one selected? Thanks!

Comment: you will be calling the whole script again? the the call is made inside the script again?

Comment: It might help to refine your requirements even further.  For example, if your results are sometimes {0,1,0,1}, would that be seen as a repeat?  For every 12 samples in sequence, do you want 12 different values in a random order, or would that be not random enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r=$last
while [ "$last" = "$r" ]
do
    r=$(($RANDOM % 12))
done
export last=$r
```

If you are calling the script again and again, then suppose the script name is `test.sh` you need to call it like `. test.sh` instead of `./test.sh`, it will make the script run in current shell. Else even the `export` is not needed. Otherwise creating a temp file approach is another robust way of getting the last value.

Comment: +1 The simple 'try again' approach is perfectly adequate for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a permutation and then pop values from it

```
perm=`echo $perm | sed 's/[0-9]\+//'` #remove the first number from $perm
if [ -z "$perm" ];then                #if perm == ""        
    perm=`shuf -e {0..12}`            #create new permutation
    #now perm="11 7 0 4 8 12 9 5 10 6 2 1 3" for example
fi
echo $perm | cut -d' ' -f1            #show the first number from $perm
```

Note that this script is **stateful**. It need to store the generated permutation between executions. Is does it by storing them in a shell variable `$perm`. Because shell scripts cannot modify the calling shell environment, you need to execute it **itside** your current shell:

```
source ./next-index.sh
```

having saved the script is to `next-index.sh` file.

You could alternatively save `$perm` to file between executions.